# Use COUNTIF, ARRAYFORMULA and VLOOKUP in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

The first two columns in my Excel sheet are used as a VLOOKUP chart as follows:

```
-----------------
| 1  | Baseball |
-----------------
| 1  | Baseball |
-----------------
| 3  | Football |
-----------------
| 4  | Football |
-----------------
```

etc...

In Column C I have a list of numbers, such as `2,1,13...`. In Column D I could do a VLOOKUP on each number to get me the sport that the number is associated with; however, I don't care about that. All I want to know is how many times each sport is represented at all, so in my short list Baseball is represented twice (2 and 1). With the VLOOKUP values I can then use a COUNTIF to count the number of times each sport shows up. In Google Sheets I can do all of this in one simple formula as follows: `=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(C1:C100,A:B,2)),"Baseball")` and I would get a number. ARRAYFORMULA doesn't exist in Excel though. Is there any way of doing this or do I need to make a hidden column for the intermediate step?

Comment: Can't you just use `COUNTIF` against the numbers and forget the names?

Comment: I want it to be expandable so that if in the VLOOKUP table you add another row for Baseball it would still work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel I would use SUMPRODUCT around a COUNTIFS():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,$C$1:$C$100,B:B,"Baseball"))
```

[image]

Comment: I think the answer is supposed to be 2.

Comment: In his example it is supposed to be 4 because rows 1,2,6 and 7 all have Baseball

Comment: Sumproduct is an array type formula,  it iterates the range in the second criterion in the COUNTIFS, it is like doing 100 countifs, one for each cell in C1:C100, and summing the output. @ZacharyWeixelbaum.

Comment: Unfortunately, this function has a huge overload. I have this formula in 200 cells and it slows down the worksheet significantly. I have to come up with a better solution, which means I will just have to do countifs against the numbers which is much faster

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum make sure you are not use a full column reference in place of the $C$1:$C$100. Your computer should be able to handle the 20,000 calculations quickly.  but if you use a full column then it is doing 21 million calculation and yes that would be slow.

Comment: Good point, currently I have C1:C100, but the VLOOKUP part I will change from A:A and B:B to A1:A100 and B1:B100